# How to pass XHR dynamically generated token in jmeter for load testing of my application

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

In my application, when i hit the URL, it generate a JWT token, which i have to pass in jmeter. How to do this.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to **extract** the token from the very first request, my expectation is that your flow looks like:

[image]

So you should be getting the [JWT Token](https://jwt.io/) in the response (body or [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)) after successful authentication.

At this stage you should be able to extract it using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and store it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html), once done you should replace hard-coded value with the JMeter Variable holding the dynamic token.

Your screenshots contain only **requests**, hence we cannot come up with an appropriate regular expression, you either need to update your question and provide **response** containing the token.

If for some reason it is not possible you can try out recording your scenario using [BlazeMeter Proxy Service which is capable of exporting recorded scripts in SmartJMX format](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80/) with automated correlation applied.